# How come that in an AC curcuit with one resistor $i_R \geq \Delta v_R$?

Tags: electric-circuits

I seem to be getting tripped up over the following portion in my notes: if we have an AC curcuit with one resistor and
$$i_R=I_{max} \sin (\omega t)$$
$$\Delta v_R = i_R R$$
how come the author includes the following graph?
[image]

Shouldn't the labeling be opposite? I understand that this would work if $0 < R < 1$, but what about $R \geq 1$?

Comment: There are two vertical axes superimposed on one another: one for the current and one for the voltage so $V_{\rm max}$ could be $10 \rm V$ and $I_{\rm max}$ could be $2 \rm A$.

Comment: Current and voltage have different units and therefore you can't compare them. The graph is just for illustration.

Comment: @Farcher I'm aware the axes are overlayed -- my question is even taking those values would mean $$R=\frac{V_{max}}{I_{max}}=5 \Omega$$ which implies $\Delta v_R \geq I_R$ but that isn't what the graph indicates

Comment: @Javier Is the goal of the graph just to show they vary in synchronization?

Comment: Yes, most likely.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it a two graphs as shown below with the voltage and current in phase with one another.

[image]